# Getting URL alias of a term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I am writing a module, and am confused about the term's URLs. because, if pathauto moduel is installed, then the alias of that module should be provided. How to achieve this?

Default drupal's URL: `taxonomy/term/30`
Pathauto's probable pattern:

```
category/30
category/[title]
category/[title]/[id]
...and millions of other possible patte
```

Using `drupal_get_path_alias()` returns drupal's default path.

How should I get the path used by pathauto? I have seen pathauto's module,
but it does not provide an API for this purpose as it seems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function. It will return aliased path if you have pathauto installed.

Example:

```
$link = url('taxonomy/term/1');
```

Comment: drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/[id]') will also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `url()` or `drupal_get_path_alias()` but make sure that your path argument doesn't have leading slash.

Example:

```
drupal_get_path_alias('/taxonomy/term/1');
url('/taxonomy/term/1');
```

Returns path `'/taxonomy/term/1'`

```
drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/1');
```

Returns `'tags/some-tag'`

```
url('taxonomy/term/1');
```

Returns `'/tags/some-tag'`

Comment: Useful knowing about the leading slash! Thank you!